# What does this '::' do in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I've started learning Classes in C++ and have come across this `::` operator. I have no idea what it means and how/when to use it. It was in every piece of C++ code I'd ever seen. The tutorial I watched didn't explain what it is. Could anyone explain?

Comment: Pick up a book and read. YouTube videos are not a good place to start learning.

Comment: `::` identifies a member of a class, namespace, etc. Can you share a piece of code so we have something on which to base any answers? I would also agree that written content is far better than a YouTube video; whilst a video generally demonstrates how to write a piece of code, it is not a good medium for actually discussing the underlying principles.

Comment: It's simply for scope resolution. You can have for example two functions with the name "cout" , one std::cout and one whatever_you_want::cout .

Comment: @ParsaMousavi But what is the use/purpose of it??

Comment: @Serket It prevents name clash in your code which can result in unwanted behavior.

Comment: @Serket It's possible to live without it , for example in C there is no namespace.But it's there to help you write a better code.